Linphone SDK: Library not loaded: @rpath/liblibbelle-sip-tester.dylib
I faced the this issue since upgrade to xcode 16 and running on device ios18.
I have done few work out from ChatGPT and StackOverflow, seems nothing fixed the issues.
Here's are few thing I done but still fail (just to make sure no one shares the same non-workout solution):

Change the Always Embed Swift Standard Libraries to YES.
Add the linphonetester.xcfromework in the list of embedded binaries.
Upgrade all dependencies to ios13 or ios15
Re-install & restart xcode
Add runpath  @executable_path/Frameworks
Add other linker flag -rpath @executable_path/Frameworks

These step I followed, but nothings worked out. Its been almost 2 weeks from the update to xcode 16.
Here's the podfile:
platform :ios, '15.6'
source "https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/podspec.git"
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"

def basic_pods
    pod 'linphone-sdk', '> 5.4.0-alpha'
end

target 'MyApp' do
  use_frameworks!
  
  pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.14.0'
  
  basic_pods
  
  pod 'ModalPresenter'
  pod "Firebase"
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
end

I have posted issues on the official linphone github repos, but seems no replies yet.

Have you tried using the Swift Package Manager instead of CocoaPods?

Tried already, but it seems the Linphone on Package Manager is different version from the current linphone app and not even work. Even from linphone documentation suggest using pod instead of package manager.

I am also facing the same issues. If you are able to find a solution, please post and if I'm able to find I'll update as well. Also, did you try switching to any older releases ?

@AnkitKhanna try my walkthrough on my answer in github and stackoverflow. I tried it as benoit suggests and it works.

Here's my walk-through base on @benoit-martins (linphone github) suggestion and it works very well. Thank you!
Walkthrough: Setting Up Linphone SDK for iOS with CocoaPods
Prerequisites
Ensure you have the following installed on your system:

Ninja Build System: Install it with brew install ninja.
Meson Build System: Install it with brew install meson.
Xcode Command Line Tools: Install with xcode-select --install.
Python 3: Verify installation with python3 --version.


Step-by-Step Guide
1. Clone and Prepare the SDK Repository

Clone the SDK repository to your local machine:
cd /Users/<YOUR USERNAME>
git clone https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk.git
cd linphone-sdk


Update the repository and its submodules:
git pull
git submodule update --init --recursive



2. Set Up Python Environment

Upgrade pip:
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip


Create and activate a virtual environment:
python3 -m venv venv
source venv/bin/activate


Install the required Python modules:
pip install pystache six


Confirm the modules are installed:
pip list




3. Build the iOS SDK

Run the cmake command (inside the activated virtual environment):
cmake --preset=ios-sdk -G Ninja -B IOS_64_RELEASE \
  -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=$(which python3) \
  -DENABLE_PQCRYPTO=YES \
  -DLINPHONESDK_IOS_ARCHS=arm64 \
  -DENABLE_NON_FREE_FEATURES=YES \
  -DENABLE_GPL_THIRD_PARTIES=YES \
  -DENABLE_G729=YES \
  -DCMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES=ReleaseWithDebInfo


Build the SDK:
cmake --build IOS_64_RELEASE --config RelWithDebInfo -j5




4. Verify the Build Output
Check if the build output exists at the following path:
/Users/<YOUR USERNAME>/linphone-sdk/IOS_64_RELEASE

The folder should contain the linphone-sdk.podspec file.

5. Configure Your CocoaPods Podfile

Edit your Podfile to include the local build of Linphone SDK:
platform :ios, '15.6'
source "https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git"

def basic_pods
  pod 'linphone-sdk', :path => '/Users/<YOUR USERNAME>/linphone-sdk/IOS_64_RELEASE'
end

target 'MyAppLinphone' do
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'SQLite.swift', '~> 0.14.0'
  pod 'ModalPresenter'
  pod "Firebase"
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'

  basic_pods
end




6. Install CocoaPods Dependencies
Navigate to your project directory where the Podfile is located and run:
pod upgrade
pod install


7. Test Your Application
Run your app to verify the integration works successfully.
